# rundeck question - enable auto-refresh on activity - its disabled by default

Tags: rundeck

Running into an inconvenience of a default and not settable via the gui. The subject says it all. Auto-refresh in Activity pane of rundeck GUI is off by default. How to set it for an all-user default of 60 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Right now doesn't exist a way to enable by default and set a custom interval for Activity panel, you can suggest that [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).